# Can HA Proxy be configured to forward an SSL port IN ADDITION to 443?

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, proxy, haproxy

I want to route BOSH HTTPS traffic on port 5281 through HA Proxy. HA Proxy is already routing SSL on port 443. I.e., I want to encrypt both port 443 and 5281 with the same certificate. 443 is forward to my web cluster. 5281 is forwarded to my XMPP server.

I use Tutum docker cloud management, so I am using their dockerized version of HA Proxy. But I don't see a way to do what I want here: https://github.com/tutumcloud/tutum-docker-clusterproxy

By comparison, I can do this with Amazon Load Balancer, but I still have to forward that to HA Proxy to balance my containers, because ALB does not handle port-level balancing and HA Proxy is nicely integrated through linked containers. But in the process I lose my X-Forwarded-Proto header (it is not concatenated like X-Forward-For), so in this set up I can't tell if the originating traffic is SSL-encrypted (and redirect it accordingly). Such a set up is also a bit complex - one load balancer in front of another in different environments - yuck.

Any ideas how to get HA Proxy to do the whole thing?

Comment: I've posted an answer, although I'm not entirely sure if I've fully understood what you're asking.  Also, there's no reason why you should "lose" X-Forwarded-Proto in a cascade from ELB -> HAProxy, which is a setup I use fairly often in my environments (different sites, different SSL certs hitting the same cluster, in an environment where SNI isn't a viable option, I have ELB offloading the SSL work).  HAProxy should pass it through if ELB is setting it, which it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, it's simple enough to direct HAProxy to listen on any port for https traffic.

```
frontend https-on-another-port
    bind *:5281 ssl no-sslv3 crt /etc/haproxy/path-to-ssl-cert.crt
```

You can also automatically add the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header on outbound connections if SSL was used on the inbound connection.  Within any proxy declaration:

```
http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto http unless { ssl_fc }
```

`ssl_fc` is a built-in boolean test for "frontend connection uses SSL" (or TLS).